# XSLT for an XML file

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xslt

I am trying to extract few tags using XSLT , but tags are getting blank value. Can you please suggest what is the issue with the code.
Below is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">ClientID</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">AssetClass</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ClientID"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="AssetClass"/></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the XML from which I am trying to pull the data.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<template123 xmlns="http://www.markit.com/totem/api/data/V40" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ClientID>470</ClientID>
  <ValuationDate>2019-01-31</ValuationDate>
  <AssetClass>Value</AssetClass>
  <ServiceName>Oil</ServiceName>
  <ServiceFrequency>ME</ServiceFrequency>
  <SubArea>10</SubArea>
  <SchemaVersion>40</SchemaVersion>
  <Underlier>
    <ContractGroup>Chemicals</ContractGroup>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <ReferencePublication1>XYZ</ReferencePublication1>
    <Underlying>ABC</Underlying>
    <Underlying1>ABC</Underlying1>
    <Instrument>
      <CCYScalar>1.0</CCYScalar>
      <EndDate>2019-02-28</EndDate>
      <InstrumentType>Watch</InstrumentType>
      <InstrumentType1>Watch</InstrumentType1>
      <Period>Month</Period>
      <PricingTime>LDN 16:30</PricingTime>
      <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
      <Units>MT</Units>
      <ClientPrice>472.84000000</ClientPrice>
    </Instrument>
    <Instrument>
      <CCYScalar>1.0</CCYScalar>
      <EndDate>2019-03-31</EndDate>
      <InstrumentType>Watch</InstrumentType>
      <InstrumentType1>Watch</InstrumentType1>
      <Period>Month</Period>
      <PricingTime>LDN 16:30</PricingTime>
      <StartDate>2019-03-01</StartDate>
      <Units>MT</Units>
      <ClientPrice>456.46600000</ClientPrice>
    </Instrument>
    <Instrument>
      <CCYScalar>1.0</CCYScalar>
      <EndDate>2019-04-30</EndDate>
      <InstrumentType>Watch</InstrumentType>
      <InstrumentType1>Watch</InstrumentType1>
      <Period>Month</Period>
      <PricingTime>LDN 16:30</PricingTime>
      <StartDate>2019-04-01</StartDate>
      <Units>MT</Units>
      <ClientPrice>440.30900000</ClientPrice>
    </Instrument>    
  </Underlier>  
</template123>
```

Have tried with the suggested solution and able to get the parent nodes values but nested node is still coming as blank.

My Updated Code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ab="http://www.markit.com/totem/api/data/V40">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="ab:template">
        <xsl:text>ClientID|ValuationDate|AssetClass|ServiceName|ServiceFrequency|SubArea|SchemaVersion|ContractGroup|EndDate</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ClientID" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ValuationDate" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:AssetClass" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ServiceName" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ServiceFrequency" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:SubArea" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:SchemaVersion" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:Underlier/ContractGroup" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:Underlier/Instrument/EndDate" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to extract the data from this XML and convert it into a pipe separated file.

Can you suggest what needs to be changed to access the values from nested nodes.

Expected output should look like as below :

ClientID|ValuationDate|AssetClass|ServiceName|ServiceFrequency|SubArea|SchemaVersion|ContractGroup|EndDate
470|2019-01-31|Value|Oil|ME|10|40|Chemicals|2019-02-28
470|2019-01-31|Value|Oil|ME|10|40|Chemicals|2019-03-31

and so on for all nested nodes.

Comment: Try `<xsl:template match="template123">` instead of `<xsl:template match="/">`...

Comment: @potame : No filtering is there if I use <xsl:template match="template123">
Output comes as 
"470 2019-01-31 Commodities Oil ME 10 40 Chemicals USD ARGUS BUTANE FE CARGO BUTANE FE CARGO 1.0 2019-02-28 Swap Swap Month LDN 16:30 2019-02-01 MT 472.84000000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ab="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="ab">
    <xsl:template match="ab:template123">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2>My Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">ClientID</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">AssetClass</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ab:ClientID"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ab:AssetClass"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**DEMO**
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWB2
XML File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template123 xmlns="http://www.markit.com/totem/api/data/V40" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ClientID>470</ClientID>
    <ValuationDate>2019-01-31</ValuationDate>
    <AssetClass>Value</AssetClass>
    <ServiceName>Oil</ServiceName>
    <ServiceFrequency>ME</ServiceFrequency>
    <SubArea>10</SubArea>
    <SchemaVersion>40</SchemaVersion>
    <Underlier>
        <ContractGroup>Chemicals</ContractGroup>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <ReferencePublication1>XYZ</ReferencePublication1>
        <Underlying>ABC</Underlying>
        <Underlying1>ABC</Underlying1>
        <Instrument>
            <CCYScalar>1.0</CCYScalar>
            <EndDate>2019-02-28</EndDate>
            <InstrumentType>Watch</InstrumentType>
            <InstrumentType1>Watch</InstrumentType1>
            <Period>Month</Period>
            <PricingTime>LDN 16:30</PricingTime>
            <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
            <Units>MT</Units>
            <ClientPrice>472.84000000</ClientPrice>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <CCYScalar>1.0</CCYScalar>
            <EndDate>2019-03-31</EndDate>
            <InstrumentType>Watch</InstrumentType>
            <InstrumentType1>Watch</InstrumentType1>
            <Period>Month</Period>
            <PricingTime>LDN 16:30</PricingTime>
            <StartDate>2019-03-01</StartDate>
            <Units>MT</Units>
            <ClientPrice>456.46600000</ClientPrice>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <CCYScalar>1.0</CCYScalar>
            <EndDate>2019-04-30</EndDate>
            <InstrumentType>Watch</InstrumentType>
            <InstrumentType1>Watch</InstrumentType1>
            <Period>Month</Period>
            <PricingTime>LDN 16:30</PricingTime>
            <StartDate>2019-04-01</StartDate>
            <Units>MT</Units>
            <ClientPrice>440.30900000</ClientPrice>
        </Instrument>    
    </Underlier>  
</template123>
```

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ab="http://www.markit.com/totem/api/data/V40">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="ab:template123">
        <xsl:text>ClientID|ValuationDate|AssetClass|ServiceName|ServiceFrequency|SubArea|SchemaVersion|ContractGroup|EndDate</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ClientID" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ValuationDate" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:AssetClass" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ServiceName" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:ServiceFrequency" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:SubArea" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:SchemaVersion" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:Underlier/ab:ContractGroup" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab:Underlier/ab:Instrument/ab:EndDate" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT:

```
    ClientID|ValuationDate|AssetClass|ServiceName|ServiceFrequency|SubArea|SchemaVersion|ContractGroup|EndDate
470|2019-01-31|Value|Oil|ME|10|40|Chemicals|2019-02-28
```

Comment: why we need to introduce additional namespace `ab`?

Comment: My actual XMLs have a different URL other than xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform". So using the namespace ab, can get the required output.

Comment: @Amrendra Kumar namespace come in xml input file so we can't remove namespace.

Comment: @Sandy : I have updated the input xml above. But could not ge the values for nested nodes. can you suggest here please.

Comment: @Swatantra Srivastava you change template match name ab:template instes-of ab:template123 and add child element namespace prefix ab:Underlier/ab:ContractGroup, ab:Underlier/ab:Instrument/ab:EndDate

Comment: Thanks @Sandy for the suggestion. It is working as expacted.

Answer (score 0):

Look like two things are wrong in you scenario:

1. Default NameSpace in XML is exact match with transformation namespace
2. In match context you are on document node so either you need to use `template123` in match or in `<xsl:value-of select="template123/ClientID"/>` & `<xsl:value-of select="template123/AssetClass"/>` you give the proper path to navigate the elements.

Below is the code you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">ClientID</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">AssetClass</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="template123/ClientID"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="template123/AssetClass"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see this link for your reference:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxZ/1

Comment: From your XML need to remove default namespace or change with different URL and closing tag of root element was missing.

Comment: Thanks Amrendra. After changing the URL can see it working. But can not change the actual URL for each XMLs.